# What are these fragile green plants with small yellow blooms in Santa Fe?

Tags: identification, ground-cover

We are having cold Winter temperatures below 10 °F at night and I find a thick patch of these fragile green plants, some with small yellow blooms, all in a part of the yard that we do not water.  I'm in Santa Fe, New Mexico, so we have a limited number of plants available.  Photos show clump of plants.

[image: plant group]

Comment: They look rather like dandelions, only not quite - what were the flowers like? Daisy type with thin narrow petals, or rounded petals or other form?

Comment: I think they are dandelions, just stressed dandelions or dandelions in shade.  One hell of an incredibly useful plant...

Comment: Not the dandelion (_Taraxacum_), but one of the the [Damned yellow composite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damned_yellow_composite). I would go to _Senecium_ (groundsel), a "nice" weed from Europa.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi, why a comment and not an answer?

Comment: @Stephie: I'm not sure. I need to look my books.

Comment: It doesn't smell like mustard, does it? If it's composite family, it could have a more dandelion-like or carrot-like smell.

Comment: From a search on Google Lens, it appears they are either dandelions, or stemless evening primrose. The latter has much more fragile looking flowers than dandelions.

Comment: These look like Dandelions, sometimes blooming yellow.

Answer (score 1):

Either a London Rocket or dandelion. Perhaps Dandelions owing your location and invasive nature of dandelions in southern US.

Comment: Dandelion has already been suggested more than once in comments.  Can you support Rocket in any fashion ?

Comment: @RohitGupta an ambiguous point I considered when answering is the color of blooms said by the OP, Arugula blooms just like dandelion blooms are yellow albeit being entirely different in the structure. Refer arugula blooms: https://savvygardening.com/arugula-flowers/

Comment: @JayparthMore Welcome to the site!

Comment: @MackM Thanks a ton!